# calculating last column balance with sql code

Tags: sql

guide me please with the sql query to calculate the balance column

tables information :
tables :- transactions ,accounts

transactions table  fields : ref_no,accounting_dt,debit_credit,amt,currency,account_no
accounts table fields   : account_no,account_name,bal_on_a_day, currency

Data in the tables

Transaction table

```
ref_no  accounting_dt   debit/credit         amt    currency    Balance
ab523   02/02/2018           D                10    840         10555589
bc654   03/02/2018           C                20    840         10555589
ab588   05/02/2018           D                20    840         10555589
bc655   05/02/2018           D                60    840         10555589
ab589   06/05/2018           C                80    840         10555589
bc656   06/05/2018           C                80    840         10555589
```

Accounts table

```
account_no  account_name    bal_on_a_day     currency
10555589    Vishal            500              840
10558889    Amit              520              840
55558889    Rohit             880              840
70561089    Anup              990              840
93062739    Sneha             440              840
15564389    Smita             560              840
```

Result must be like this :

```
ref_no  accounting_dt       debit_amt   credit_amt  Balance
bal_on_a_day                                        500 
ab523    02/02/2018          10                     490  (500-10)
bc654    03/02/2018                       20        510  (490+20) 
ab588    05/02/2018          20                     490  (510-20)
bc655    05/02/2018          60                     430  (490-60) 
ab589    06/05/2018                       80        510  (430+80) 
bc656    06/05/2018                       80        590  (510+80)
Total dr,cr,clos bal         90          180        590
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Requesting experts to help me